# why click event is not working when its created on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have:

On the client:

```
<asp:imagebutton id="icon2" runat="server" visible="false" imageurl="images/icon_info.gif" width="16" height="16" imagealign="AbsMiddle" style="cursor:pointer;" alternatetext=""></asp:imagebutton>
```

On the server:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton icon2 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("icon2");
icon2.AlternateText = string.Format(Sales.Common.Res.key("basket.message.material.change") + ". ", line.altMaterial, line.materialCode);
icon2.AlternateText = "";
icon2.Click += icon2_Click;

public void icon2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //todo
}
```

But `icon2_click` is not working when i click this `imagebutton`.

Why?

I know about `onClick` on the client, but I should add this event on server because this image is not always clickable.

Comment: Where in your WebForm (which method) are you creating the event? ASP.NET Page has an [event life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140); you're probably creating the event after it'd be checked.

Comment: "I know about onClick on the client, but I should add this event on server because this image is not always clickable." . This does't make sense. client-side click and server-side click do two different things. One causes JavaScript to run within the browser, and the other one causes the page to post back to the server and run a C# method, and then refresh the page.

Comment: Whether the image is clickable or not doesn't dictate your choice of client- or server-side click. You can still add client-side click to those which are clickable, and not add it to those which aren't. Or use server-side for those which are clickable, and don't use it for those which aren't. The logic is the same in both cases. Whether you choose client-side or server-side click depends on what you want to happen when the image is clicked.

Comment: I highly doubt the client is getting an asp:imagebutton tag.
You need to add an event handler for the button click on the server. the easiest was to do that is to add it to your markup

Comment: FalcoGer, yes. client getting image. Thank you!

Brendan Green, thank you for edit my question!